# Comparing index values with loc selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm filtering rows using a [loc selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

The dataframe has the following structure, where `type` and `index` are indices.

```
type | index | col1 | col2
a    | 0     | 2    | 1
b    | 1     | 5    | 1
b    | 2     | 3    | 4
```

I want to change the value of `col2` based on 2 conditions:

1. the value of `col1` is less than the one in the next row
2. the two rows have different values for the index `type`

I already tried using `index`:

```py
df.loc[(df['col1'] >= df['col1'].shift(-1)) & (df.index != df.shift(-1).index), 'col2'] = 0
```

and it gives me this error:

`ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`

I also tried `df["type"]`:

```py
df.loc[(df['col1'] >= df['col1'].shift(-1)) & (df["type"] != df["type"].shift(-1)), 'col2'] = 0
```

but it gives me key error:

`KeyError: 'type'`

Comment: Is your expected output supposed to be zero in the first row for col2 only?

Comment: Your solution is correct but you should reset the index to make type a column, otherwise you can't access it that way.

Comment: no, it's based on the value of col1; just decided to simplify

Comment: I don't understand. So is your output _not_ [0, 1, 4]? Can you please add the expected result then?

Comment: do not use `df.index`, this refers to your actual index, not the column named `index`. Instead, use `df['index']`. And it looks like you `type` column is the `index`,  not a column.